# n coin balancing problem

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

[Rank weights of coins with a balance scale](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356708/rank-weights-of-coins-with-a-balance-scale)

I want to generalized above problem into $n$ coins.

i.e.,

> using balance scale, sort $n$ coins in order.

Slightly more generalizing the above post, [In that post, they didn't consider equal weight case] Let's consider, when we balance scale, there are three possibilities. [Let a,b the two coins, then a=b, a>b, a

Making trees for $n=5$, I obtain the number of weighting is 7.

And by the similar computation [with more effort] I figure out for $n=6$, 10 is enough.

How about its generalization to $n$?

At this moment I have no idea how to generalize for $n$.

In searching internet, I found one particular arXiv,
[1409.0250](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0250.pdf), but in there analysis is not matched even in $n=5$. [For example, I thought the section 4 of that paper is the same case with mine, but it seems not...]

Comment: In the paper you linked to, the $n$ coins are assumed to be of only three different weights. That may explain why the results don't match what you're getting.

Comment: This is in general an open problem. See https://oeis.org/A036604

Comment: @MikeEarnest, Wow!!! Thanks for the information!